# Clojure tools.analyzer, don't expand macros

Tags: dynamic, clojure, macros, analyzer

What is the best way to avoid expanding macros when creating ast's using `tools.analyzer.jvm/analyze`

This is an example of the information I am currently collecting:
(map of function name to dependency set)

```
  {some-function
  #{{:name load-order-ns-file-maps, :ns #namespace[clj-graph.core]}
    {:name *logger-factory*, :ns #namespace[clojure.tools.logging]}
    {:name analyze, :ns #namespace[clojure.tools.analyzer.jvm]}
    {:name make-dir-tracker, :ns #namespace[clj-graph.core]}
    {:name enabled?, :ns #namespace[clojure.tools.logging.impl]}
    {:name read-all, :ns #namespace[clj-graph.core]}
    {:name get-logger, :ns #namespace[clojure.tools.logging.impl]}
    {:name traverse-expr, :ns #namespace[clj-graph.core]}
    {:name log*, :ns #namespace[clojure.tools.logging]}
    {:name track-reload,
     :ns #namespace[clojure.tools.namespace.reload]}
    {:name examine-form, :ns #namespace[clj-graph.core]}}}
```

The actual code calls `log/info` but as this is macroexanded, I can never capture the the name and ns in which it was declared - instead I get the macro expansion giving me:

```
:name *logger-factory*, :ns #namespace[clojure.tools.logging]
:name enabled?, :ns #namespace[clojure.tools.logging.impl]
:name get-logger, :ns #namespace[clojure.tools.logging.impl]
:name log*, :ns #namespace[clojure.tools.logging]
```

As I am building a dependency graph, ideally I just want to find the endpoints, ie `:name info :ns #namespace[clojure.tools.logging]`.

Reading the documentation for `analyzer.jvm/analyze` it gives an example as:

```
(analyze form env {:bindings  {#'ana/macroexpand-1 my-mexpand-1}})
```

but when I try this, ie:

```
(defn ^:dynamic my-expand-1 [form] form)

(ana/analyze
 '(defn prnt [xs] (my-pre-defined-macro xs))
 (ana/empty-env)
 {:bindings  {#'ana/macroexpand-1 my-expand-1}})
```

I get the error

```
IllegalStateException Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var:
clojure.tools.analyzer.jvm/macroexpand-1  clojure.lang.Var.pushThreadBindings (Var.java:320)
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If macros were not expanded, you couldn't get any useful information, because what a macro expands into is completely opaque to you. Perhaps someone has written this function:

```
(defn foo [x]
  (-> x
      inc
      println))
```

If you don't expand the `->` macro, you will not find out that `foo` depends on `inc` and `println`. And finding out that it depends on `->` is not very interesting.

Comment: Sure, but if `->` had been defined by the user - at the moment, the expansion causes it to 'dissapear' - at least from what I can tell. I can't find a var in the ast. But the problem is that I can't tell from the ast what is a macro or not. What I think I want to do is expand so that I can capture the arguments and test them - but ignore all the crud that goes into '->' . I *dont care* how `->` is defined, I just want to know where it comes from (and yes, the arguments it takes)

Comment: Do you understand what I mean from the example I gave in the question - can you see that there is no reference to `log/info` even though this was the macro that was called.

Comment: With your example, `(macroexpand '(-> 10 (partial + 1)))` becomes `(partial 10 + 1)` but `->` is **vital** because if it was re-written the outcome would change. I think i'm just going to write my own parser...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for specific macros by providing implementations of `macroexpand-1` and `parse`. My `macroexpand-1` implementation ignores the specific macros I want to parse myself (by simply returning the form) and my `parse` implementation provides custom parsing. You can pass custom method bindings in the options to `analyze`:

For example, to provide custom parsing of the `binding` macro:

```clj
(require '[clojure.tools.analyzer.jvm :as ja])
(require '[clojure.tools.analyzer :as ana])
(defn my-parse [[op & _ :as form] env]
  (if (= op 'binding)
    (merge (ana/parse-let* form env)
      {:op :unexpanded-dynamic-binding})
    (ja/parse form env)))

(defn binding-form? [o] (and (seq? o) (= (first o) 'binding)))

(defn my-macroexpand-1
  ([form] (my-macroexpand-1 form (ja/empty-env)))
  ([form env]
   (if (binding-form? form)
     form
     (ja/macroexpand-1 form env))))

(ja/analyze
  '(binding [*clojure-version* 1] *clojure-version*)
  (ja/empty-env)
  {:bindings {#'ana/parse my-parse 
              #'ana/macroexpand-1 my-macroexpand-1}})
```